# Reference for url query strings parameters in the WorkItemEdit.aspx in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, user-acceptance-testing

If users experience an exception in UAT they'll log a bug in TFS, eg:

```
public void TopLevelExceptionHandler(Exception ex)
{
...
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Settings.Default.TFSBugReportingURL + ex);
```

http://tfsportal/CompanyName/ProjectName/_layouts/tswa/UI/Pages/WorkItems/WorkItemEdit.aspx?**wit=Bug**&[System Info]=

See the `wit` query string parameter (a.k.a Work Item Type), where is
the reference to these query string parameters for this WorkItemEdit.aspx page?

**I'm trying to set the AssignedTo field.**

**EDIT:**
This is how you set the free text Title field and the drop down list priority field:

[Title]=FixSomeBug&[Priority]=1&

I just cannot work out the AssignedTo field? I'd also like to know how to access the [Steps to Reproduce] field.

**EDIT 2:**

I looked through the SDK, and stumbled up on it: &[Assigned to]=THOMPSON, Jeremy&

---

**EDIT 3:**

> There is an easy way to get the url for the work item template. When
>   you create a new work item in Team System Web Access, there is a
>   button available "Copy Template URL" to get the url that reflects the
>   changes you made to the work item.

As usual Ewald is to the rescue, unfortunately my screen doesn't have the "Copy Template URL" button:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me to see the hidden "Copy Template URL" button was in the URL I used:

http://tfsportal/CompanyName/ProjectName/_layouts/tswa/UI/Pages/WorkItems/WorkItemEdit.aspx <- doesn't show the button.

http://tfs.CompanyNameURL:8080/tfs/web/wi.aspx?  <- does show the button

Answer (score 1):

If you fill out a bug form, you can use the Copy Template URL button in the toolbar to find out how you should construct the URL. See an image of the button at http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/06/Initial-values-in-a-work-item.aspx

Comment: Could you please see my edit 3 Ewald, no wonder it seemed so difficult - I'm missing that "Copy Template URL" button. You wouldn't happen to know how to get it to show? Sorry this is turning into a chameleon question.

Comment: It is possible that this is added to SP1 of TFS2010 (not sure what version brought this functionality). Just checked on one of our TFS2010 servers. What version are you running?

Comment: Anyway, if I click on that button, I get the following querystring parameters: wit=Bug&%5BSystem.AssignedTo%5D=Ewald%20Hofman

Comment: TFS2010 SP1, Project Admin rights. A colleague with Project Collection Admin rights helped me find out how to set the Steps To Reproduce with his Copy Template URL button: http://tfs:8080/tfs/web/wi.aspx?wit=Bug&%5BSystem.Title%5D=Please%20detail%20the%20bug&%5BSystem.AssignedTo%5D=THOMPSON%2C%20Jeremy&%5BMicrosoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps%5D=%3CP%3EStep%201.%3C%2FP%3E%0D%0A%3CP%3EStep%202.%3C%2FP%3E    `BUT GET THIS, WHEN I USED THE LINK ABOVE I CAN NOW SUDDENLY SEE THE COPY TEMPLATE URL button`